# ember.js localstorage adapter cannot load relationships (ember-cli)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm having trouble getting relationship data from localstorage when loading a model in the route.

The first time I get the data from the server through an ajax request everything is fine but as soon as I get to a new route and reload the data all the relationship have disappeard.

I don't understand how to reload these relationship! Ideally I would like to call the user-exam model and get all the hasMany array as well.

thanks for your help.

here are my two models

import DS from 'ember-data';

exam-question.js:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    question : DS.attr('string'),
    questionID : DS.attr('string'),
    answer1 : DS.attr('string'),
    answer2 : DS.attr('string'),
    answer3 : DS.attr('string'),
    answer4 : DS.attr('string'),
    answer5 : DS.attr('string'),
    answer6 : DS.attr('string'),
    answer7 : DS.attr('string'),
    numberOfAnswers : DS.attr('number'),
    solutions : DS.attr('string'),
    examID : DS.attr('string'),
    chosenAnswers : DS.attr('string'),
    result : DS.attr('string'),
    userexam: DS.belongsTo('user-exam')
});
```

user-exam.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  salesforceid : DS.attr('string'),
  name : DS.attr('string'),
  examType: DS.attr('string'),
  resultPercentage : DS.attr('number'),
  result : DS.attr('string'),
  numberOfQuestions : DS.attr('number'),
  rightAnswers : DS.attr('number'),
  passingPercentage : DS.attr('string'),
  questions: DS.hasMany('exam-question')
});
```

on my account.js route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('user-exam');
    },
    afterModel: function() {
        var applicationController = this.controllerFor('application');
        if (!applicationController.isLoggedIn) {
            this.transitionTo('index');
        }
        this.controllerFor('account').send('loadData');
    }
});
```

& controller (on first load I manage to populate all data and relationships are mapped perfectly)

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['application', 'newexam-modal'],
    isLoading: true,
    actions:{
        loadData: function (){
            console.log(this);
            this.send('loadExamTypes');
            this.send('LoadUserExams');
        },
        LoadUserExams: function () {
            var applicationController = this.get('controllers.application');
            var store = this.store;
            var accountController = this;
            var userexams = store.findAll('user-exam');
            accountController.setProperties ({isLoading: true});
            userexams.then(function() {
                var userProperties = applicationController.getProperties('useremail','currentToken');
                var requestdata = '{ "action": "GetExams","useremail":"'+userProperties.useremail+'","secretToken":"'+userProperties.currentToken+'"}';
                Ember.$.ajax({
                    url: "my server url",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: requestdata,
                    success : function (data) {
                        //window.console.log(data);
                        if (userexams.content.get('length') !== data.get('length')){
                            data.forEach(function (item){
                                var examname = item.Name;
                                store.find('user-exam', { name: examname }).then(function(){
                                },function() {
                                        console.log("items"+item);
                                        store.createRecord('user-exam', {
                                            salesforceid : item.Id,
                                            name : item.Name,
                                            resultPercentage : item.Exam_Result_Percentage__c,
                                            result : item.Exam_Result__c,
                                            numberOfQuestions : item.Number_of_Questions__c,
                                            rightAnswers : item.Right_Answers__c,
                                            passingPercentage : item.Passing_Percentage__c,
                                            examType : item.Exam_Type__r.Name
                                        }).save().then(function (createdexam){
                                            console.log(item.Exam_Questions__r.records);
                                            item.Exam_Questions__r.records.forEach(function (question){
                                                store.createRecord('exam-question', {
                                                    question : question.Question__r.Question__c,
                                                    questionID : question.Name,
                                                    answer1 : question.Question__r.Answer_1__c,
                                                    answer2 : question.Question__r.Answer_2__c,
                                                    answer3 : question.Question__r.Answer_3__c,
                                                    answer4 : question.Question__r.Answer_4__c,
                                                    answer5 : question.Question__r.Answer_5__c,
                                                    answer6 : question.Question__r.Answer_6__c,
                                                    answer7 : question.Question__r.Answer_7__c,
                                                    numberOfAnswers : question.Question__r.Number_of_Answers__c,
                                                    solutions : question.Question__r.Solutions__c,
                                                    examID : question.Exam_Name__c,
                                                    chosenAnswers : question.Answer_Chosen__c,
                                                    result : question.Result__c,
                                                    userexam : createdexam
                                                    //store.find('user-exam', {name: item.Name})
                                                }).save();
                                            });

                                        });
                                });
                            });
                        }
                        accountController.setProperties ({isLoading: false});
                    },
                    error : function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            });

        },
        deleteExamData: function() {
            console.log('deleting user exams');
            this.store.findAll('user-exam').then(function(record){
                record.content.forEach(function(rec) {
                    console.log('deleting exam'+rec);
                    Ember.run.once(this, function() {
                        rec.deleteRecord();
                        rec.save();
                    });
                }, this);
            });

        }       
    }
});
```

On my account template I use linkto to display the user-exam data. The first time I click on the button the data loads in template with all associated child records. But When I go back to account route and click on the view exam again the child records disappear

```
{{#link-to 'exam' this}}view exam »{{/link-to}}
```

here is my exam.js route

```
import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Route.extend({
        examid:'',
        model: function(params){
            return this.store.find('user-exam', params.exam_id);
        },
        serialize: function(model){
            return {exam_id:model.get('id')};
        },
        setupController: function(controller, exam) {
            controller.set('model', exam);
        },
        afterModel: function() {
            var applicationController = this.controllerFor('application');
            if (!applicationController.isLoggedIn) {
                this.transitionTo('index');
            }
            this.controllerFor('exam').send('loadData' );
        }
});
```

my exam.hbs

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>This is Exam: {{ name }} !</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    {{ questions }}
    {{#each question in questions}}
      {{question.name}}<br />
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

my router map:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('register');
    this.route('application');
    this.route('login');
    this.route('account');
    this.resource('exam', { path: 'exams/:exam_id' });
    this.route('settings');
});
```

My localstorage setup is done like so with the ember-cli addon

my application.js adapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.LSAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'sfdquiz'
});
```

and serializer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.LSSerializer.extend({

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a stupid error! question.name didn't exist.

```
    {{#each question in questions}}
      {{question.name}}<br />
    {{/each}}
```

But I changed the pattern loading all the data at once was making the app too slow. I used the aftermodel to go fetch the related objects from the server and connect them to their parent at that moment.

```
 model: function(params){   
    return this.store.find('user-exam', params.exam_id);
 },
 afterModel: function(exam) {
        var applicationController = this.controllerFor('application');
        if (!applicationController.isLoggedIn) {
            this.transitionTo('index'); 
        } else {
            this.controllerFor('exam').send('loadData', exam.get('id'));
        }
 }
```